# Why does PHP create this step down issue in my css based menu?

Tags: php, html, css

I am just learning web dev. I am using php in my menus. I am doing this so my users information is displayed when the user is logged in, within the menu itself. I do this with the Session super global array variables. For any of the two different kind of users that login, these variables store whether they are logged in and what their name is. This way the menu can react to adding them to the menu. My issue is that it seems that by simply using php drags my horizontal to the next level, or what I have seen people call "stepdown".

I have a jfiddle of the same sort of information running without php.

Without php, no step down:
https://jsfiddle.net/bx1jsnoL/

Stepdown looks like this on my side, which has php code echoing html code:
[image]

Here is my php on my side:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


        <div class="nav">
         <ul> 
            <li><a href="index.php">Home  </a></li>


            <li><a href="dates.php">Dates  </a></li>
            <li><a><i>Information  </i></a>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="about.php">About the conference</a></li>
                <li><a href="fee.php">Conference Fee</a></li>
                <li><a href="hotelinfo.php">Hotel Information</a></li>
                <li><a href="registrationforconference.php">Conference Registration</a></li>
                <li><a href="program.php">Conference Program</a></li>
                <li><a href="guidelines.php">Guidelines</a></li>
                <li><a href="keynote.php">Keynote Speakers</a></li>   
                <li><a href="call.php">Call for Paper</a></li>
                <li><a href="major.php">Major Areas</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="comments.php">Comments  </a></li>

                <?php

        session_start();


        if(isset($_SESSION['loginstatus']) && $_SESSION['loginstatus']==true)
            {
            echo "<li><a id='orange'><i><b>Reviewer<b></i></a><ul>";
            echo "<li><a id='orange'><i><b>" . $_SESSION['username'] . "<b></i></a></li>";
            echo "<li><a href='logout.php'> Log out</a></li><li><a href='reviewerregister.php'>Registration</a></li>
                    <li><a href='submission.php'>Paper</a></li>
                    </ul></li>";

            }
            else
            {
                echo "

                    <li><a><i>Reviewers  </i></a>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a href='login.php'> Log in</a></li>
                    <li><a href='reviewerregister.php'>Reviewer Registration</a></li>
                    <li><a href='submission.php'>Paper Submission</a></li>
                    </ul>



                ";

            }

        ?>

        </li>

        <?php


        session_start();
        if(isset($_SESSION['adminstatus']) && $_SESSION['adminstatus']==true)

            {
                echo "<li><a id='orange'><i><b>Admin<b></i></a><ul>";
                echo "<li><a id='orange'><i><b>" . $_SESSION['adminname'] . "<b></i></a></li>";
                echo "<li><a href='logout.php'>Log out</a></li>
                <li><a href='admindbmanagement.php'>Management</a></li>
                      </ul></li>";


            }


        else
            {
            echo "

                    <li><a><i>Admin  </i></a>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a href='adminlogin.php'> Log in</a></li>
                    </ul>

                ";
            }


            ?>

        </ul>
        </div>
```

Here is my css, it is included in the jfiddle but the editor here won't let me get away without any code:

```
table, th, td
{
    border:1px solid #99d9f4;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;

}

form, table
{
                text-align: center;
margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto;
}

td
{
    padding: 10px;

}



#orange
{
    color:orange;
}

th
{
 /*   background-color:#99d9f4; nothing happens
    color:white;*/
    }


.enlarge:hover 
{

    transform:scale(2,2);
    transform-origin:0 0;
}

#dates li
{
 margin: 10px 0;   
}

h1
{
/*     text-decoration: underline;
 */ text-transform: capitalize;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px #FFFFFF, 1px 1px 1px #000000;
    color: white;


}

p, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6
{
color:white;    
}

* {
 font-family: Georgia, serif, Arial;
}
/* this addresses all text
 */

 input[type="submit"] 
 {
     background:green;
     color: white;
     height: 1.01 em;
    width: 1.01 em;
    font-size: 110%;
 }

 input[type="file"]
 {
     color:white;
     height: 1.01 em;
    width: 1.01 em;
    font-size: 110%;

 }

  input[type="reset"] 
 {
     background:red;
     color:white;
     height: 1.01 em;
    width: 1.01 em;
    font-size: 110%;
 }


body
{
        background-image: url('background.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
        }



input
{
    color: black;
}

textarea
{
    color: black;
}



/* line-height 0 gives some odd text */
.nav ul {
  list-style: block;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;

 font-size: 110%;

}
  .nav > ul > li {
    text-align: center;


  }




.nav li {
   display: inline;

}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  transition: .3s background-color;

}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #005f5f;
}

.nav a.active {
  background-color: #aaa;
  color: #444;
  cursor: default;
}

/*submenus */
.nav li li {
  font-size: .6em;
}


  .nav li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;

    width: inherit;
  }

  ul.menu li
  {
     display:inline; 
  }


  .nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
  }

  .nav li ul li {
    display: block;
  }
}

  .nav > ul > li > a {
    padding-left: 0;
  }



/* 650px screens */

@media screen and (min-width: 650px) {
  .nav li {
    width: 130px;
    border-bottom: none;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 1.0em;
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

Comment: @KostasMitsarakis this is not the problem; trying to run PHP in an HTML-only environment is the problem.

Comment: For the record, this question is not up to the site's standards. Even though it's all about PHP, you didn't include even one line of PHP code here. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Give me a minute, I'll update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that because your PHP isn't being interpreted as PHP; it's being interpreted as (broken) HTML. Running PHP code (and avoiding having it rendered as HTML) requires a server running PHP, the software.

jsFiddle doesn't run PHP code, so you can't test PHP on there. You can only test HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

---

**EDIT:** based on your edits to the question and your comments below, the problem is that you are calling `session_start()` twice. The resulting error is triggering output that is breaking your layout.

Comment: The issue still exists on my side when swap out the php. Why would php weigh the list down?

Comment: @munchschair if you're seeing the same thing you saw on jsFiddle, it's because you're also not parsing PHP. It's not PHP per se that causes the issue; it's that you have PHP code in the middle of a page that is being treated as pure HTML, without any parsing of the PHP beforehand. That breaks the PHP, the layout, and pretty much everything.

Comment: @munchschair you need to install PHP and access a page through a server in order to have the PHP render correctly.

Comment: I have xamp. I am running php to work my DB as well. My stepdown issue looks like what I have in the image, it is not breaking in the exact same way as the jfiddle example. I did not know jfiddle does not process php.

Comment: @munchschair I see you've updated your question. It's really hard to tell what's going on here because you have a lot of irrelevant code (i.e., code that could never have an impact on the layout). For example, you have two different calls to `session_start()`, both of which will be executed (which is a logic problem and needs to be fixed, by the way), but neither of which is relevant to the layout. You should break this down and try to isolate the problem. ***All that said, I think this is your problem:*** you have an extra `</li>` between your first closing `?>` and the following `<?php`.

Comment: I actually figured this out a little after making this on my own. I figured whatever the error is might show up in the html that is interpreted. I checked the output I was getting in html and you were right on the session_start(). It was creating an output error of some type in the html and creating a break. I had some idea in mind that php on its own may interpret poorly into a menu. But, no, it was the php itself.

Comment: @munchschair I'm glad you figured it out. I have edited my answer to reflect the solution. If you found my points helpful in solving the problem, I would appreciate it if you accepted the answer (by clicking the check mark next to the answer).